# Spark: what's the advantages of having multiple executors per node for a Job?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, executor

I am running my job on AWS-EMR cluster. It is a 40 nodes cluster using cr1.8xlarge instances. Each cr1.8xlarge has 240G memory and 32 cores. I can run with the following config:

```
--driver-memory 180g --driver-cores 26 --executor-memory 180g --executor-cores 26 --num-executors 40 --conf spark.default.parallelism=4000
```

or

```
--driver-memory 180g --driver-cores 26 --executor-memory 90g --executor-cores 13 --num-executors 80 --conf spark.default.parallelism=4000
```

Since from the job-tracker website, the number of tasks running simultaneously is mainly just the number of cores (cpu) available. So I am wondering is there any advantages or specific scenarios that we want to have more than one executor per node?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean for a given Spark Job? There are always multiple Executors per Node.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there are advantages of running multiple executors per node - especially on large instances like yours. I recommend that you read [this blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) from Cloudera.

A snippet of the post that would be of particular interest to you:

> To hopefully make all of this a little more concrete, here’s a worked example of configuring a Spark app to use as much of the cluster as possible: Imagine a cluster with six nodes running NodeManagers, each equipped with 16 cores and 64GB of memory. The NodeManager capacities, yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores, should probably be set to 63 * 1024 = 64512 (megabytes) and 15 respectively. We avoid allocating 100% of the resources to YARN containers because the node needs some resources to run the OS and Hadoop daemons. In this case, we leave a gigabyte and a core for these system processes. Cloudera Manager helps by accounting for these and configuring these YARN properties automatically.
>
> The likely first impulse would be to use --num-executors 6 --executor-cores 15 --executor-memory 63G. However, this is the wrong approach because:
>
> 63GB + the executor memory overhead won’t fit within the 63GB capacity of the NodeManagers.
>   The application master will take up a core on one of the nodes, meaning that there won’t be room for a 15-core executor on that node.
>   15 cores per executor can lead to bad HDFS I/O throughput.
>   A better option would be to use --num-executors 17 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 19G. Why?
>
> This config results in three executors on all nodes except for the one with the AM, which will have two executors.
>   --executor-memory was derived as (63/3 executors per node) = 21.  21 * 0.07 = 1.47.  21 – 1.47 ~ 19.

Comment: There is also the trade offs in heap size impact on garbage collection.

Comment: @ChristopherB, could you elaborate a little bit more about "trade offs in heap size impact on garbage collection" ? Thanks!

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt: So in the above Couldera example, the 1 executor per node config uses up to 63G memory per node, while the 3 executors per node configuration uses up to 19Gx3 = 57G memory per node. Would 3 executors per node waste the (63-57) = 6G memory per node in such case? especially if it is a memory intensive job? Thanks!

Comment: As for jvm heap size, the larger the heap size the GC may need to pause longer to compact. At this point in time EMR uses CMS GC to minimize pauses even in larger heap sizes but don't discount the potential impact of size on JVM performance. Beyond memory efficiency as noted by Glennie I've seen use-cases that just performed better with smaller executors (though aggregate cores per node is the same) and vice versa. Test for your use-case.

Comment: @Edamame yes, I am unaware of a way to currently avoid memory waste with YARN. I find this to be especially related to the fact that the application manager needs to run on one of the nodes, so the best you can do in try to minimize the memory waste as described in the Cloudera post. I believe that a number of things have been done in Spark 1.6 to optimize memory utilization, but until then...

Comment: This explanation deserves more clarity. It is rather confusing TBH