# Dilemma about Spark partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am working on a project where I have to read S3 files (each about 3MB zipped) using boto3. I have a small pyspark script that runs every hour to process the file and generate 2 types of output data which is written back to S3. The pyspark script uses 'xmltodict' python library to read some static data into a dictionary object needed for file processing. I have a small Amazon EMR cluster v5.28 running with 1 Master and 1 Core. This might be excessive but is not my main concern right now.

Questions:
1. How do I know 'IF' i should partition the data? I have read articles on how many partitions to create, etc but couldn't find anything on IF and WHEN. What is the criteria that drives partitioning - number of rows, columns, data type, actions taken in the script, etc in the source data file? I read the source file into an RDD and convert it to a DF and perform various operations by adding columns, grouping data, counting data, etc. How does spark handle partitioning behind the scenes? 
2. Currently, I manually execute the pyspark script as follows:

```
spark-submit --master spark://x.x.x.x:7077 --deploy-mode client test.py
```

on the master node as I have decided to stick with Standalone CM. The 'xmltodict' is installed on this node, but is not installed on the Core node. It doesn't seem like it needs to be installed or even python3 configured on Core node since I am not seeing any errors. Is that correct and can somebody shed some light on this confusion? I tried to install the python libraries via shell file as a bootstrap 
when I created the cluster, but it failed and quite frankly after trying it a few times, I gave up.
3. Based on partitioning I think I am slightly confused on whether or not to use coalesce() or collect(). Again, the question is when to use and when not to?

Sorry too many questions. Now, that I have the pyspark script written, I am trying to work the efficiencies. 
Thanks

Comment: three questions in one breath :) Let me try to answer one about partitioning.

Comment: Here are some resources that may help understanding partitioning [Top 5 Mistakes When Writing Spark Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyfHUNnMutg), [Tune Apache Spark Jobs](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/), [Executors, Cores and Memory](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html) and the [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348167/spark-whats-the-advantages-of-having-multiple-executors-per-node-for-a-job). By the way you should avoid posting 5 question or more question in one

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is the mechanism with which data is divided into optimum size chunks and based on that multiple `tasks` are run, each processing one piece of data. As you see this is the core of parallelism and without this there is no significant use of Spark (or any bigdata processing framework). Most of the file formats are splittable and some are splittable when compressed like Avro, parquet, orc etc. Some file formats are not splittable when compressed like - zip, gzip etc. Based on the size of the file being processed and their ability to be split, Spark automatically creates multiple partitions and processes data in parallel. In your case the data being zip, one file will be one partition and no more than 1 CPU can work on it at once. If this zip is small then its ok, but if it is big then its processing will be slow.